# How to set bias value of a particular layer in Keras

Tags: keras

I was trying to set bias value of a particular layer in Keras, but I didn't find any way to do that.

For example weight can be set by following code:

```
model.layers[-1].set_weights(weights)
```

Is there any way to set bias, the way weights can be set (like above)?

Can anyone help me in this regard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `K.set_value` for this :
   `K.set_value(model.layers[-1].weights[1], np.ones((bias_dim,)))`

Note that when you use `set_weights`, you have to provide a list containing both weights and biais, so if you would only want to set the weights without setting the biais, you could also use `K.set_value`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But, I can't quite figure out the format of the weights matrix you use. Please, correct me if i am wrong. weights[1] stands for layer weight and weights[0] for layer bias.

Comment: No problem. That's the opposite, weights[0] is the kernel (matrix) and weights[1] is the bias (vector). You can see it if you print `model.layers[i].weights`

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by setting constraints for biases or weights or both.

in each layer there are bias_constraint and kernel_constraint that they are for biases and weights respectively.
Here is the example if you want to set bias value to 1.

```
model.add(Dense(1 ,bias_constraint=tf.keras.constraints.MinMaxNorm(
min_value=1.0, max_value=1.0, rate=1.0, axis=0), activation='softmax'))
```

Answer (score 0):

In tensorflow `.get_weights()` method on layer returns weights and bias of that layer.
To set any layer weight and bias just use `.set_weights()` method. for example to set `layer_b` weights and bias from `layer_a` do as follow:

```
layer_b.set_weights(layer_a.get_weights())
```

for reference you can refer [`set_weights`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Layer#set_weights)